# height of UISlider in a horizontal UIStackView

Tags: ios, uistackview, ios-autolayout

The arranged subviews in `UIStackView` with a horizontal axis must have the same height with the `UIStackView`'s height. However it is not true for a `UISlider`. Whatever height I set for `UIStackView`, the height of `UISlider` in the stack view will have 1px taller height.

[image]

I set `UIStackView`'s height as 40 and didn't set any auto layout for the `UISlider`.

[image]

But the height of `UISlider` is 41 which I expected 40.

Is there any reason for this? and any way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UISlider` seems to do some odd stuff with its sizing.

Ignoring the stack view for the moment, if you simply apply width and height constraints to a `UISlider`, they won't match the *actual* width and height at run-time. You get an extra `4-pts` width and an extra `1-pt` height.

***However...***

If you constrain another view relative to the slider, the other view *respects the slider's constraints, not the slider's rendered size.*

Take a look at this image-capture from Debug View Hierarchy:

[image]

- Slider has

  - `width = 100`
  - `height = 40`

but the orange rect (the slider background) is actually `104 x 41` - and that's what you'll get if you `print(mySlider.frame)` at run-time.

- Left Label has

  - `trailing = slider.leading`
  - `height = slider.height`
  - `centerY = slider.centerY`
- Right Label has

  - `leading = slider.trailing`
  - `height = slider.height`
  - `centerY = slider.centerY`

Both label heights are exactly 40-pts - which matches the **constraint**.

Note also that the label frames *overlap* the slider background by `2-pts`, showing that the label x-positioning is, again, matching the **constraints**, not the rendered slider view frame.

If you inspect the views when the slider is embedded in a `UIStackView`, you will see (well, you *have* seen) that the frame size is greater than the stack view's frame. But, the slider's frame will extend *outside* the actual frame of the stack view... the stack view (and its other arranged subviews) will continue to respect the constraints you've given it.

All of which is to say... if the "size mismatch" is not causing any issues, I wouldn't worry about it.